# Haystack facet is case sensitive

Tags: django, django-haystack

User model has a field which contains user`s city.

On search site I want to show how many users in cities registered, so I use facets:

```
result = search_query_set.facet('city')
result = result.facet_counts()
```

The problem is that when users will add a city using different letter case, i. e. Warsaw and warsaw then after calling facet I will have in result different attribute for Warsaw and for warsaw. Is it possible to force haystack to join Warsaw and warsaw together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you create new model field holds all uppercase version of that field
then facet over this field

Comment: this is a soulution, but i was wondering if there is a way for doing it just using haystack

Comment: this also haystack solution you need to create facets over this field :)